# Маленький шрифт в консоли Eclipse (где пишет информацию о компиляции и прочее)

Tags: eclipse

У меня маленький шрифт в области Eclipse`а, где выводится информации о постройки проекта, ошибки итп, проблема в прикреплённом фото, нужно сделать текст побольше, пробовал CTRL + , CTRL -.

[image: Текст который нужно увеличить]

Comment: Решение лично  моей проблемы я нашёл:

зайти в Window -> Preferences -> General -> Appearance -> Colors And Fonts 
в открывшемся справа окне (ваш язык, у меня это C/C++) -> Editor, и то что вам надо изменить, то и трогайте, у меня это Build Console Text Font

Answer (score 0):

Решение лично моей проблемы я нашёл: зайти в Window -> Preferences -> General -> Appearance -> Colors And Fonts в открывшемся справа окне (ваш язык, у меня это C/C++) -> Editor, и то что вам надо изменить, то и трогайте, у меня это Build Console Text Font